# Erro 'NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação com vários pacotes e utilizando o spring cloud com Eureka em java, mas essa exceção.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:206) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) [spring-cloud-context-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at com.kn.packagecontrol.packagecontrolbackend.PackageControlBackendApplication.main(PackageControlBackendApplication.java:13) [main/:na]
```

[image: Application.yml]

[image: Estrutura]

[image: bootstrap]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE')
    classpath('gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:gradle-plugin-publishing:5.2.4')
}
}
subprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

group 'com.kn'
version '0.0.1'

sourceCompatibility = 8

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
test {  useJUnitPlatform() }
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
}
project(':api-packaging') {
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.9.0'
    implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.9.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19'
}
}
```

Comment: Poste a estrutura do projeto se possível. Como as classes estão organizadas nos pacotes.

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Aparentemente é algo com a versão do Spring Boot. Tente a versão 2.2.0 ou superior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe `ConfigurationPropertiesBean` não está sendo localizada.

A classe foi lançada a partir da versão 2.2.0 do Spring ([documentação da classe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBean.html)) e olhando pela sua stackTrace vc parece estar usando a versão 2.1.3. Portanto, atualize a versão do seu Spring.

(Sem o POM do seu projeto, não sei qual dependência vc está utilizando, acredito que seja web-starter, então usarei ela como opção)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**REPOSITÓRIO MAVEN**

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: Muito obrigado me ajudou aqui, porém no meu caso era a versão do spring cloud que é muito recente aí não estava batento com a versão do Spring Boot que é mais antiga.